# gcc - Linking multiple shared library

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

#### background knowledge:

First I explain what do I understand of these `gcc` flags so far:

> **`-L`:** As the gcc manual states, this flag add specified directory "to the list of directories to be searched for **`-l`**"

> **`-l`:** Again as manual said, "Search the library named library when linking."

So, what I understand of these two, is first one adds directories to a list which, named library by the second one will be searched in, by the linker!

> **`-I`:** As for this, manual says: "Add the directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for header files during preprocessing"! So I assume this one does the same as **`-L`** but for header files.

> **`-Wl`:** The -Wl portion sends comma-separated options to the linker

#### What I'm trying to do:

I want to compile/build an executable which uses 3 .so shared libraries; And 2 of those (`libpq` and `libsqlite3`) are provided by official 3rd party vendors (Postgresql and Sqlite); And installed with `apt install`.
The 3rd one is one of mine; I wrote it myself and trying to link it with my executable to be able to use it at runtime.

#### What I tried so far:

If I compile my code without my own library (and respective function inside the code) using below command, it works fine:

```sh
g++ -std=c++20 full.cpp -o loadTester -L/usr/include/postgresql/libpq -lpq -lsqlite3
```

However, using these command, to also link my own library with my code, I get errors:

```sh
gcc -std=gnu17 -shared -o liblogwritter.so -fPIC logWritter.c
g++ -std=c++20 full-with-logger.cpp -o loadTester -L/usr/include/postgresql/libpq -L./ -lpq -lsqlite3 -llogwritter -Wl,-rpath=./ -I./
```

I've also tried by replacing `./` parts with the full path: `/home/username/Desktop/Current/`.

#### Error:

```sh
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccSFD38J.o: in function `pgConncetionInit(char const*)':
full-with-logger.cpp:(.text+0xc3): undefined reference to `logWritter(char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccSFD38J.o: in function `pgInsertQuery(char**)':
full-with-logger.cpp:(.text+0x709): undefined reference to `logWritter(char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccSFD38J.o: in function `main':
full-with-logger.cpp:(.text+0x1994): undefined reference to `logWritter(char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: full-with-logger.cpp:(.text+0x19e2): undefined reference to `logWritter(char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: full-with-logger.cpp:(.text+0x1b0e): undefined reference to `logWritter(char const*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

#### Code for the library:

**`logWriter.c`:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

#define SV_SOCK_PATH "/tmp/shahab_logger"

int logWritter(const char* messageData)
{
    struct sockaddr_un addr;

    // Create a new client socket with domain: AF_UNIX, type: SOCK_STREAM, protocol: 0
    int sfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // Construct server address, and make the connection.
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(addr.sun_path, SV_SOCK_PATH, sizeof(addr.sun_path) - 1);

    if (connect(sfd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting to server\n");
        return 0;                
    }

    write(sfd, messageData, strlen(messageData));

    close(sfd);
    return 0;
}
```

**`logWriter.h`:**

```c
#ifndef LOGWRITTER_H
#define LOGWRITTER_H
 
int logWritter(const char* messageData);
 
#endif  // LOGWRITTER_H
```

**`myprogram.cpp`:**

```cpp
... //Several lines removed

logWritter(jobExecTime.c_str());

... //Several lines removed
```

---

#### Note:

I made a simple driver program for my library as below and it was working fine (Provided that I ran the `server.c` before to accept socket connection):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "logWritter.h"

int main()
{
    printf("Test driver program!\n");
    if (logWritter("Test driver program!") > 0)
    {
        printf("Error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And I compiled this driver program as below:

```sh
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic logWritter.c
gcc -shared logWritter.o -o liblogwritter.so
gcc -Wall testDriver.c -o testDriver -L/home/username/Desktop/logger/ -llogwritter -Wl,-rpath=/home/username/Desktop/logger/
```

---

#### Note 2:

Here is the list of files inside `/home/username/Desktop/Current/` (which all files exist) just in case:

```sh
activity_main.db  full.cpp  full-with-logger.cpp  liblogwritter.so  logServer
logWritter.c  logWritter.h  postgresInit.sql  run.sh  server.c  sqliteInit.sql  unix_socket.h
```

---

### Question:

I think it obvious at this point, after reading such lengthy post (**my greatest regards and appreciation for your king effort and time in advance**) but to follow standards here:

1. Are my understanding which I explained in the first section, correct?
2. What am I missing (knowledge-wise)?
3. How should I compile my executable? Please explain for both two cases which I copied the header file in `/usr/include/` and shared library file in `/usr/local/lib`, or if I want to link them from current working folder, as it is now in the case of examples above.

Comment: ***Are my understanding which I explained in the first section, correct?*** Yes.

Comment: `-L/usr/include/postgresql/libpq` is wrong but unnecessary. This is a header path not the location of the library. It's unnecessary because the library should have been installed by your package manager in `/usr/lib` which will be in a system path that your linker already searches by default.

Comment: Edited 2x now. duh!: `-L/usr/include/postgresql/libpq` ?? Usually `-L` directories are like `/usr/lib/`, but `/usr/include` is usually where the `-I` files live. It also strikes me that the `libpq` tail end of your `-L` is a file, not a directory, but I have not experience with postgresql.   Good luck.

Comment: @drescherjm That is correct, thanks for correction. Sometime in the development, I had an error which solved by adding these flags and I made mistake with capital i and capital L

Comment: @shellter You are right; I fixed it. Though `libpq` in `/usr/include/postgresql/libpq` is actually a directory!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you define `logWritter` in .c, it must be declared with C linkage when used in C++, hence logWriter.h must be

```
#ifndef LOGWRITTER_H
#define LOGWRITTER_H
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int logWritter(const char* messageData);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```